# How can I draw autoshape on an already existing image in Word 2003?

Tags: image-editing, microsoft-office-2003, drawing, microsoft-paint

I'm drawing autoshape in Word 2003 like this:

[image]

**Is there anyway I can draw that shape over an existing image?** I cant seem to get that done on existing image. I tried pasting the image in Word, but I cant emboss the autoshape on it.

**Note:** I know I should be using real image editing tool for this purpose, but the reason I use Word 2003 is that it has amazing autoshapes. I tried with MS Paint, but it doesnt have a cool **curve drawing** feature like as shown in the picture above, and the built in shapes are pretty limited. **Or is there a image editing tool tool which have many auto shape templates built in as in Office suite?** Should be lightweight so that I can quickly download a copy.. I dont need any other heavy features..

Comment: If Paint doesn't meet your requirements, then I think you should try more powerful drawing program (like [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)). Using a word processor for drawing doesn't sound reasonable to me.

Comment: @gronostaj thanks for the help. Yes I really want a simple drawing software lil more powerful than MS Paint. I tried gimp but it doesnt have it too (it seems its an image editing software!). I will try Inkscape.

Answer (score 0):

Google's online drawing (which is a part of google docs) does have this. I was after [this kind of curve drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_spline#Cardinal_spline). Some information [here](http://googledocs.blogspot.in/2010/08/new-curve-tool-for-drawings.html).